# Are there any gases that can not be turned into liquid, or liquids that can not be frozen solid?

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

My son points out that some solids can not be melted (because they combust, for example). He wonders if there are any liquids that can not be frozen, or gases that can not be liquified.

Comment: Related:   https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29729/why-cant-helium-be-solidified-at-ordinary-pressures.

Comment: Some liquids separate on freezing. For example, Sn/Pb solder, other than the eutectic alloy, form separate phases of tin-in-eutectic or lead-in-eutectic on cooling. Thus, on freezing, the alloy changes from a fully-dispersed soluton to separate components. See http://www.uefap.com/reading/exercise/ess3/alex2.htm

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37413/sublimation-of-iodine/37416#37416

Comment: All gases can be compressed into a condensed phase, assuming no chemical reaction occurs, but it might be interesting to point out that for Helium (to my knowledge uniquely) just reducing the temperature is not sufficient, pressure is required as well - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_helium